# Printing radio button numeric values to a text box

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I was just wondering how do Print the selected radio value to the text box dynamically, so that the value in the text box matches the value of the corresponding selected radio button, using javascript? Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm just starting out with javascript and am finding it tough!

p.s. I am only familiar with javascript so sorry to the people who helpfully posted JQuery solutions! I do appreciate it!

HTML Code:

```
<h2>Configuration</h2>
<div>
<input type ="radio" id="gtmanual" name="car" value="277790.00" checked="checked" >
<label for ="gtmanual">GT Manual -  &euro; 27,7790.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtauto" name="car" value="28,500.00" >
<label for ="gtauto">GT Automatic -  &euro; 28,500.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtsmanual" name="car" value="32,450.00">
<label for ="gtsmanual">GT-S Manual -  &euro; 32,450.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtmanual" name="car" value="33,155.00">
<label for ="gtsauto">GT-S Auto -  &euro; 33,155.00 </label>
 <br>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" id="total" readonly>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
var total=0
var carcost=0

gtmanual=document.getElementById("gtmanual")
gtmanual=document.getElementListner("click" calculateCar, false);

window.onload=function calculateCar() {
var mycar=document.getElementByName("car");
 for (var i=0; i<mycar.length; i++)
 {
         if (mycar[i].checked) {
             carcost = parseFloat(mycar[i].value);
             break;
          }
          var total+= total+carcost=0;
     }

 document.getElementById("total").value=total;


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code.this is in javascript as per your requirement

```
   <html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
function getvalue(temp)
{
document.getElementById("total").value=temp.value;
}
</script>
<h2>Configuration</h2>
<div>
<input type ="radio" id="gtmanual"  name="car" value="277790.00" onclick="getvalue(this)">
<label for ="gtmanual">GT Manual -  &euro; 27,7790.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtauto"  name="car" value="28,500.00" onclick="getvalue(this)">
<label for ="gtauto">GT Automatic -  &euro; 28,500.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtsmanual"  name="car" value="32,450.00" onclick="getvalue(this)">
<label for ="gtsmanual">GT-S Manual -  &euro; 32,450.00 </label>
<br>
<input type ="radio" id="gtmanual"  name="car" value="33,155.00" onclick="getvalue(this)">
<label for ="gtsauto">GT-S Auto -  &euro; 33,155.00 </label>
 <br>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" id="total" readonly>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for the solution in javascript, thanks for replying though!

Comment: @user2988501 i have edited answer as a javascript..refer answer

Answer (score 3):

I have created what you wanted but its done with jQuery:

Link to the full working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/b7YNp/

jQuery:

```
$('input[name="car"]').change(function(){
    $('#total').val($('input[name="car"]:checked').val());
});
```

Comment: Hey I appreciate the answer but I neglected to mention I'm not familiar with JQuery code, thanks for taking the time out to reply, I do appreciate the response though!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/DU2AZ/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#total").attr("value", $("input:radio[name='car']:checked").val());
$("input").on('click', function(){
$("#total").attr("value", $("input:radio[name='car']:checked").val());
});
});
```

Comment: Hey I appreciate the answer but I neglected to mention I'm not familiar with JQuery code, thanks for taking the time out to reply, I do appropriate!

Answer (score 1):

you can do by this simple JS-

example : [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sharif084/LvrvG/)

```
var rad = document.getElementsByName('car');
var value = null;
for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
    rad[i].onclick = function() {
    value=document.querySelector('input[name="car"]:checked').value;
    document.getElementById('total').value=value ; 
  };
}
```

Comment: @user2988501 for dynamic radio button you can use this.